# How to measure "clumping" in workload

Tags: overdispersion, clumping

I'm trying to come up with a succinct measurement of the dispersion of employee effort in a services firm.

All employees work on projects. Hypothesis: the fewer projects an employee works on in a time span, the more productive that person will be (measured in billed hours), due to lowered context switching and communication overhead, etc.

It's easy to count the number of projects employee X works on in a month, and compare that to productivity. But the project count isn't enough.

Jack might work on 20 projects for 8 hours each in a month. This seems to be "maximally dispersed". Or he could spend 92% of his time on one project, and a tiny bit on each of the other 9. This is much "less dispersed."

Is there a statistical measure that can distill this idea of dispersion? Wikipedia tells me about the "index of dispersion" (variance squared over mean). But this seems adapted to clumping of events within time or space areas, and assumes that "normal" dispersion is something like a normal or Poisson distribution. (We've never measured a "typical" dispersion of time over projects -- it might very well be normal- or Poisson-like).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Your question, as phrased, doesn't seem to take into account task switching. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but if I alternate tasks, that is something different than weighting for time spent per task (as you describe), right? I think you'd need some indicator of the amount of times switching between tasks occurs.